# How to find telegram first/last name with his phone number

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I have his phone number. But I want to see his first name in telegram. I can not ask him directly. Is there any api to get his first name with his phohe number? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't quite understand what you meant, but if you need a bot that displays information about the user, then here it is)

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from aiogram.utils import executor

API_TOKEN = "your_token"
bot = Bot(token=API_TOKEN, parse_mode='HTML')

storage = MemoryStorage()
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start_message(message):
    keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1, resize_keyboard=True)
    button_contact = types.KeyboardButton(text="SEND PHONE NUMBER", request_contact=True)
    keyboard.add(button_contact)

    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Please, send me your phone number!", reply_markup=keyboard)


@dp.message_handler(content_types=['contact'])
async def phone_message(message):
    if message.contact is not None:
        userid = message.from_user.id
        username = message.from_user.username
        firstname = message.from_user.first_name
        lastname = message.from_user.last_name
        user_phone = message.contact.phone_number
        language = message.from_user.language_code
        await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "User ID: " + str(userid) + "\n" +
                               "Nickname: " + username + "\n" +
                               "First name: " + firstname + "\n" +
                               "Last name: " + lastname + "\n" +
                               "Language: " + language + "\n" +
                               "Phone number: " + user_phone)
    else:
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'User phone number is empty!')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Can you please tell me how do I use this bot..? Thank you..